# HERE Maps using HTML5 Geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, maps

I have a problem using the HTML5 Geolocation API with HERE Maps. First I made a test document which works properly:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');

var coords = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

function success(position) {
      test.innerHTML = 'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude +
                       "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d8age6ss/

After that I tried to add that code into my HERE Map:

```
var coords = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

function success(position) {
    var location = '{ lat: ' + position.coords.latitude + ', lng: ' + position.coords.longitude; + ' }'
}        

function setView(map) {
    map.setCenter(location);
    map.setZoom(12);
}
```

What I do not see is what is wrong. On https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps it is said that HTML5 Geolocation is supported.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you have a local variable in your `success` function:

```
function success(position) {
    var location = ...
}
```

Only that function can use that variable.  So when you try to use it again in the `setView` function, it won't know what it is.

```
function setView(map) {
    map.setCenter(location);
```

Instead what you need to do is either make `location` a global variable, or pass it as a parameter into your `setView` function.  e.g.

```
var location;

function success(position) {
    location = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
    };
}        

function setView(map) {
    map.setCenter(location);
    map.setZoom(12);
}
```

(Also `location` doesn't need to be created as a string, so I amended that slightly).

I don't see where you call `setView` from?

Comment: Thanks for your help! The `setView` is called after initializing the map in a div container. It centers the map to the given coordinates. Sorry for that. It is my first question here and I tried to fulfill all requirements while asking it.